# Smooth-scroll shakes on mobile devices (CSS, HTML, forms)

Tags: css, forms, input, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to build a scrollable form, but when I add fieldsets and inputs, the form shakes and does not scroll smoothly on mobile devices, especially when using Ipad and Iphone.

Here is the pen: http://codepen.io/ahayes8/pen/GrrpJy

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="table vh-100 w100">
    <div class="table-cell middle">
        <div class="modal mt2 w100 center">
            <input id="modal__trigger" type="checkbox"> <label for="modal__trigger">open form</label>
            <div aria-describedby="modal_desc" aria-labelledby="modal__title" class="modal__overlay" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-outter">
                    <div class="modal__wrap">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="table mb2 col-12" id="nav" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #fff">
                                <h2 class="table-cell middle col-9" id="modal__title">Headline</h2>
                                <div class="table-cell middle col-3 right-align">
                                    <label for="modal__trigger">×</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac laoreet elit. Phasellus dignissim purus vitae urna cursus, quis congue ligula tristique. Ut nec blandit risus. Donec at orci ut justo venenatis viverra. Suspendisse in volutpat lacus. In enim est, dapibus eget ipsum sed, suscipit ultrices diam.</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac laoreet elit. Phasellus dignissim purus vitae urna cursus, quis congue ligula tristique. Ut nec blandit risus. Donec at orci ut justo venenatis viverra. Suspendisse in volutpat lacus. In enim est, dapibus eget ipsum sed, suscipit ultrices diam.</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac laoreet elit. Phasellus dignissim purus vitae urna cursus, quis congue ligula tristique. Ut nec blandit risus. Donec at orci ut justo venenatis viverra. Suspendisse in volutpat lacus. In enim est, dapibus eget ipsum sed, suscipit ultrices diam.</p>
                            <div>
                                <form>
                                    <div>
                                        Please complete the required fields.
                                    </div>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label>Field 1</label><input type="text" value="">
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label>Field 2</label><input type="text" value="">
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label>Field 3</label> <input type="text" value="">
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label>Field 4</label> <input type="text" value="">
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label>Field 5</label> <input type="text" value="">
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label>Field 6</label> <select>
                                            <option value="">
                                                Please select a category..
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="1">
                                                Cat #1
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label>Field 7</label> 
                                        <textarea></textarea>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <div id="usp-submit">
                                        <input type="submit">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my relevant CSS. The full is in the pen.

```
.modal {
  display: inline-block;
}

fieldset {
    margin-top:2rem;
    margin-bottom:2rem;
}

.modal__overlay {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 600;
}

.modal-outter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:  #ef3c42;
}

.modal__wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1.75em;
}

.modal-content {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


input:checked ~ .modal__overlay {
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 800;
}

#modal__trigger {
position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
}

fieldset label  { width: 100%;}
fieldset input { width: 100%;}
textarea {width: 100%;}
select { display: block; width: auto; margin: 0; }
```

Is there a way to fix this and make the form scroll without jumping/shaking?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the pulse animation and `overflow-y: scroll;` to the `.modal__wrap` class after that no jump/shake maybe this case help.

```
   .modal-outter {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #ef3c42;
    }

.modal__wrap {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 1.75em;
}
```